# Intellectual property in the age of Industry 4.0

Tags: learning-algorithms, legal, business

I am looking for specific references describing guidance principles around the interplay between IP (intellectual property) and Artificial Intelligence algorithms. For example, Company A has a large dataset and Company B has advanced algorithmic capabilities (assume near-AI). How might Company A protect itself in a joint partnership with company B? Apologies if AI SE is not the place for this - any suggestions for the right site?

Comment: I think law.se might also be of help.